# Detect newlines while reading a txt file - Android

Tags: java, android

I have a simple application that read a txt file and put it in an EditText view.
everything works very fine except that I can't detect newlines from the txt file and replace it with "\n".

> for example :
>       I have this text in my file
>
> ```
>     this
>     is
>     a
>     file
>     with
>     newline
>
> but this is what I get in the Edittext view:
>
>     thisisafilewithnewline.
> ```

And this is my code:

```
private String onFileClick(Option o){

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();//--read text from file---
    String filePath = o.getPath();
    String CHARSET = "ISO-8859-1";
    String fileType = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(filePath);
    String NOT_TXT = "NOT TXT FILE";

    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), CHARSET));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            text.append(line.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n"));
        }
        br.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    if(fileType.equals("txt"))
        return text.toString();
    else
        return NOT_TXT;
}
```

I need help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text.append(line+"\n");// this will add new line into your string after reading
```

is that what you was trying to do?

Comment: No, I want just to detect the newline in file and replace it.if this file containe a title and a paragraph after it then I want to display the title then \n then the paragraph.

Comment: well you detected it. when you use readLine(); you read single line from text file.You can just make a mark on each iteration(in form of append string like \\n or whathever you like int linesDetected;   ... linesDetected+=1;)

Comment: Yhe no problem! :) next time check docs sometimes easy stuff like this can go pass the fingers as EJP pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the Javadoc. The readLine() method removes line terminators.

Comment: You can use readLine(), but instead of replacing line terminators you just have to append them.

Answer (score 1):

The reader.readLine() function removes the carriage return and linefeed as specified in the API docs):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

every "line" instance you get was terminated one way or another (\r, \n or \r\n).
So instead of replacing you could do something like

```
text.append(line + "\n");
```